FastAPI+Authlib Error: All connection attempts failed
I am trying to implement login with google in my fastapi application
I am running the fastapi application in K8S cluster:
Here is relevant code:
here is my ingress-nginx config file:
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
name: ingress-service
annotations:
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: 'true'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 50m
labels:
name: ingress-service
spec:
rules:

- host: medbot.xyz
  http:
  paths:
  - path: /api/chat/?(.\*)
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    backend:
    service:
    name: query-preprocessing-service
    port:
    number: 8000
  - path: /api/rag/?(.\*)
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    backend:
    service:
    name: rag-uploader-service
    port:
    number: 8000
  - path: /api/auth/?(.\*)
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    backend:
    service:
    name: auth-service
    port:
    number: 8000
  - path: /?(.\*)
    pathType: ImplementationSpecific
    backend:
    service:
    name: frontend-service
    port:
    number: 3000

app.py for Auth
from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
from .routes.main import router
from .database.config import Base,engine
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware
from starlette.requests import Request
import json

import os

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET")

app = FastAPI(root_path="/api/auth")

# app.add_middleware(

# # CORSMiddleware,

# allow_origins=\["\*"\],

# allow_credentials=True,

# allow_methods=\["\*"\],

# allow_headers=\["\*"\]

# )

class LoggingMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
async def dispatch(self, request: Request, call_next):
body = await request.body()
print(f"Request body: {body.decode()}")
print(f"Request headers: {dict(request.headers)}")
print(f"Request path: {request.url.path}")
response = await call_next(request)
print(f"Response status: {response.status_code}")
return response

app.add_middleware(LoggingMiddleware)
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key=SECRET_KEY)
app.include_router(router=router)

@app.get('/')
async def root():
return {"message":"Hello from auth service."}

code for routes
from fastapi import APIRouter
from starlette.requests import Request
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from starlette.config import Config
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse,HTMLResponse
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth,OAuthError
import os

load_dotenv()

router = APIRouter()

GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET")
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('SECRET_KEY')

config = {
"GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID": GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
"GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET": GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET
}
starlette_config = Config(environ=config)
oauth = OAuth(starlette_config)
oauth.register(
name="google",
server_metadata_url="https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email profile'},
)

@router.get('/login-with-google')
async def login(request:Request):
redirect_uri = request.url_for('callback')
authorization_url= await oauth.google.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)
return authorization_url

@router.get("/google-callback",name='callback')
async def callback(request:Request):
try:
token = await oauth.google.authorize_access_token(request)
print("Token: ",token)
user = token\['userinfo'\]
except Exception as error:
print("Error: ",error.error)
return JSONResponse({"working":"false"})
if user:
print(user)
return JSONResponse({"working":"true"})
return JSONResponse({"working":"false"})

Here is the entire code: https://github.com/adityabhattad2021/medbot
Relevent files:
https://github.com/adityabhattad2021/medbot/blob/main/infra/k8s/ingress-service.yaml
https://github.com/adityabhattad2021/medbot/blob/main/auth/requirements.txt
https://github.com/adityabhattad2021/medbot/blob/main/auth/src/app.py
https://github.com/adityabhattad2021/medbot/blob/main/auth/src/routes/login_with_google.py
From my browser when I try to hit http://medbot.xyz/api/auth/login-with-google
I am redirected to the google auth page, but from there when it returns to callback I am getting error:
Error:  All connection attempts failed
and sometimes
MismatchingStateError: mismatching_state: CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response
